# I want select all checkbox how to do it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want select question[0] at all

I mean question[0][][][] to question[0][3][6][9]

```
    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][][][]' value='0'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][][][]' value='1'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][][][]' value='2'>

    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][1][][]' value='0'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][2][][]' value='1'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][3][][]' value='2'>

    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][1][4][]' value='0'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][2][5][]' value='1'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][3][6][]' value='2'>

    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][1][4][7]' value='0'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][2][5][8]' value='1'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][3][6][9]' value='2'>
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq6gW.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iiD7.png)

Comment: and what you've you tried so far ?

Comment: You mean `$('input[name^=question\\[0\\]]')` ?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank you sir for your response. My problem I have is attaching to the picture in question...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and use attribute starts with selector

```
$( "input[name^='question[0]']" )
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. The problem I have is attaching to the picture in question

Answer (score 0):

From the answers above I solved my problem. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Below is how it was solved

```
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][][][]' value='0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][][][]' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][][][]' value='2'>

  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][1][][]' value='0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][2][][]' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][3][][]' value='2'>

  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][1][4][]' value='0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][2][5][]' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][3][6][]' value='2'>

  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][1][4][7]' value='0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][2][5][8]' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[0][3][6][9]' value='2'>
  
  
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][][][]' value='0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][][][]' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][][][]' value='2'>

  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][1][][]' value='0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][2][][]' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][3][][]' value='2'>

  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][1][4][]' value='0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][2][5][]' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][3][6][]' value='2'>

  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][1][4][7]' value='0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][2][5][8]' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question[1][3][6][9]' value='2'>
</div>

<input type="button" value="abc" id="abc">
```

```
$("#abc").click(function() {
  console.log("click");
  var ab = $("input[name^='question[0]']");
  for (let i = 0; i < ab.length; i++) {
    const element = ab[i];
    element.checked=true;
    console.log('checkbox');
  }
});
```